# Insert code - Markdown. Liquid Exception

Tags: markdown, jekyll, liquid

I am using jekyll 2.5.3 for blogging. I try do that:

```
{% highlight javascript %}
class RandomQuotes extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <React.NavigatorIOS
        style={styles.container}
        initialRoute={{
          title: 'Random Quotes',
          component: titleApp
        }}/>
    );
  }
}   
{% endhighlight %}
```

But because this part initialRoute={{.... }} I get this error

```
Liquid Exception: Variable '{{' was not properly terminated with regexp: /\}\}/ in... [my markdown file]
```

Someone can help me with this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to avoid Liquid variable or tag parsing, You can use the {% raw %} tag :

```
{% highlight javascript %}
class RandomQuotes extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <React.NavigatorIOS
        style={styles.container}
        initialRoute={% raw %}{{
          title: 'Random Quotes',
          component: titleApp
        }}{% endraw %}/>
    );
  }
}
{% endhighlight %}
```